# Настройка расширенной e-commerce в Google Analytics

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics, ecommerce

Друзья, проблема такая:

Есть хедер сайта где установлен код счетчика:

(Детали упустил показываю код где подключен плагин)

```
<head>
//код самого счетчика

//Плагины
          ga("create", "UA-XXXXXX-1", {"cookieDomain" : "xxx.com"});
          ga("require", "displayfeatures");
          ga("require", "ec");
          ga("send", "pageview");
</head>
```

Далее у меня идет страница с циклом товаров. В новой области видимости я заполняю информацию для передачи в GA

```
<body>

    {
      //Цикл вывода товаров на главной

     //Формирую информацию о товаре для передачи в га
     ga("ec:addImpression", {
     "id": "1",
     "name": "Тестовый товар",
     "price": "1",
     "brand": "Брэнд",
     "category": "Категория",
     "position": "1",
     "list": "Главная страница"
     });

    }
```

Как говорится в документации к плагину эл. коммерции, данные нужно передавать либо с **ga("send", "pageview");** либо с каким то ивентом.

После выхода из цикла товаров я пробую отправить ивент:

```
ga("send", "event", "Главная страница", "Просмотр акций", {"nonInteraction": true});
</body>
```

Как показали мои тесты, данные о просмотрах товаров НЕ ВЫГРУЖАЮТСЯ в полном объеме, и не соответствуют количеству реальных просмотров.

Затем я решил сделать так. Я добавил информацию о предложенном товаре в шапке сайта перед **ga("send", "pageview");**

Мой код выглядел след. образом

```
<head>
    //код самого счетчика

    //Плагины
              ga("create", "UA-XXXXXX-1", {"cookieDomain" : "xxx.com"});
              ga("require", "displayfeatures");
              ga("require", "ec");

//Формирую информацию о товаре для передачи в га
         ga("ec:addImpression", {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "Тестовый товар",
         "price": "1",
         "brand": "Брэнд",
         "category": "Категория",
         "position": "1",
         "list": "Главная страница"
         });

              ga("send", "pageview");
    </head>
```

Потом я перезагрузил страницу ровно 10 раз, и спустя несколько минут я уже получил ровно 10 просмотров по этому товару в Google Analytics.

**Собственно суть вопроса:**

Как мне сделать так что бы данные передавались нормально. Вариант решения проблемы - сделать функцию для вывода цикла и сначало вызвать ее в хедере для оформления инфо о товаре а потом уже на странице при реальном выводе, но это бред! я не думаю что кто то этим занимается. Я пробовал даже вынести

```
ga("send", "pageview");
```

в футер сайта, тоесть отправлять все в GA тогда когда страница полностью загружена и отображена, но это не принесло никакого результата. С таким способом данные по прежнему приходят не полностью, и криво.

Можно после цикла заполнения информации опять послать

```
ga("send", "pageview");
```

Но мне кажется это не корректно, так как страница загрузилась 1 раз, но информация получается попадает 2 раза!

Прошу помочь решить вопрос!

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо отправлять `ga('send', 'event' ... )` после каждого вызова `ga("ec:addImpression", { });`, т.к. `ga("send", "pageview");` выгружает только последнее или только одно событие.